# Placing an image left to text and icons to the right of text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to place some text in the middle of an icon and an image. Somehow it is not quite working out. I can't seem to get everything nice and lined out.

Here is my code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="span6">
        <img class="companyIcon" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/766/base_software/128/circle_blue.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="companyTitle span3">
        <p>Coinchase<i class="fa  fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p>Back to results <i class=" fa  fa-mail-reply " aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a visual example you can provide to illustrate to us what *exactly* you are looking for?

Comment: Here is the link of what i need - http://imgur.com/R11ZtON

Comment: So are you looking for text, specifically "Coinchase", to be inside the image **and** to the right of the image, or are you just looking for the text to be to the right of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this below
```

```css
.col-md-10 {
    float: left;
}
.col-md-10 .span6 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.col-md-2 {
    float: right;
}
.companyTitle.span3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="span6">
        <img class="companyIcon" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/766/base_software/128/circle_blue.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="companyTitle span3">
        <p>Coinchase<i class="fa  fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p>Back to results <i class=" fa  fa-mail-reply " aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```